# Why is it easier to pull a lawn roller rather than pushing it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Does it have something to do with friction or weight distribution in pulling is favorable or anything else ?

Comment: Easier for whom? Floris' force diagram is accurate, but IRL you need to take your skeleto-muscular system into account as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you push a lawn mower, you are directing force **down** as well as forward because of the angle of the handle.  This means the wheels of the mower are being pushed into the grass, which increases the rolling friction (when the wheel makes a hole in the grass, you have to "climb out of the hole" all the time; the deeper the hole, the steeper the slope you are climbing). When you pull, the force is "up and out" of the (smaller) hole - so it's easier.

A little cartoon to help:

[image]

This is ignoring the fact that most lawn mowers have a free wheel mechanism so that the blades only move when you push it forward. I don't think that's what you were asking about.

Comment: @Kumar Sambhav: If it helped, then accept it by clicking the `tick`.